# How does one output arbitrary text from INSIDE a control class in C# ASP.NET, MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, winforms, forms

Is it possible to say something to the effect of 'SomeClass.Out.WriteLine("hello world")'  and have it actually show up for the browser to render?  I ask, because I notice that the HtmlHelper BeginForm implements IDisposible.  So at the end of the using block, a closing  tag is written to the browser.

I am not saying I would use this practice, as it seems like a bad idea, but I just want a better understanding of what is going on under the hood of C# ASP MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Response.Write()` or `Response.Output.Write()`. The second gives you the possibility to format the string, likewise to the `string.Format()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This was the answer I sought.